# Serverless deploy throwing error: "Object notation for "service" property is not supported. Set "service" property directly with service name."

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, serverless-framework

I am building a microservice using Node JS serverless framework. To be honest, this is my first time building a microservice using serverless. I have configured the AWS credentials on my machine already.

I created the project running the following command.

```
serverless create -u https://github.com/codingly-io/sls-base -n aution-service
```

Then I run `npm install` inside the project folder.

This is my serverless.yml folder.

```
service:
  name: auction-service

plugins:
  - serverless-bundle
  - serverless-pseudo-parameters

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  memorySize: 256
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  region: eu-west-2
  
functions:
  hello:
    handler: src/handlers/hello.handler
    events:
      - http:
          method: GET
          path: /hello
```

I already have the lambda function that comes with the template. Then I run `serverless deploy` to deploy the service. When I run the command, I got the following error.

```
Error:
Object notation for "service" property is not supported. Set "service" property directly with service name.
```

What is wrong my configuration or code and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 31):

You can fix it by setting the name of the service directly to `service` property like this

```
service: auction-service
```

The nested notation is no longer supported.

Answer (score 3):

This is working for me. just remove `name` in `server.yaml`. Use

(✔) `service: auction-service`

❌ `service: name: auction-service`

Answer (score 0):

if you are using <node14 then go for serverless@2 it will work for your